# Java Installations and switch java versions

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have installed intelliJ and java. Without even setting up any paths or zshrc profile.  When I run a simple java program in intelliJ (by clicking the handy green play button). It picks it up and executes the program. However the same done via terminal with javac filename.java returns

```html
javac: file not found: first.java 
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Upon executing java -version; I dont have an established on.
When i setup the java_Home in .zshrc file however, java -version returns the expected Java version and I am able to execute now my java program via terminal.

Is the later setup system wide and the initial one only for the intelliJ specific project?

I am confused why intelliJ works without addition java_home setup.

Comment: Not answerable without knowing which OS, at least.

Comment: The question is kind of confusing. In IntelliJ, we can add multiple JDKs and switch between them. This is independent from what we can configure for the shell. When we type a command in the shell, the paths in `$PATH` are searched for an executable of that name. So we need to add the `$JAVA_HOME` to the `$PATH`. We can change the value of `$JAVA_HOME` to point to a different JDK version. There are tools (e.g. [lmod](https://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) with which we can manage multiple versions, but those are advanced tools.

Comment: setting up java_home may be harmful for IntelliJ IDEA. It is better to point /sur/bin/java to the correct java path, or add java SDK installation to path variable.